# In Python Regex, how can I express the following pattern of strings?

Tags: python, regex

In Python Regex, how can I express the following pattern of strings?

Suppose I have two subpatterns p1 and p2. I would like the pattern for any of the following cases:

- p1p2 (p1 appears immediately before p2)
- p1 (no p2)
- p2 (no p1)

It is not possible that the two patterns don't exist at the same time.

Comment: https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html

Comment: What about `p2p1`? Is that a match or not?

Comment: Maybe `(p1)(p2)?|(p2)`

Comment: Another option can be to make all optional but use a negative lookahead to prevent matching empty strings: [`^(?!$)(?:p1)?(?:p2)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/2RzqFU/1) If the patterns start with a word character, you can also use a word boundary `\b` instead of the lookahead ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/2RzqFU/2)).